# most efficient way to get various variables out of a string

Tags: c#, string

I'm currently working on a remote control software. The unit delivers the following string (without any linebreak or something):

```
...some_general_infomations,param1=value1,param2=value2,param3=value3,paramN=valueN,...
```

I need somehow to assign these values to some variables. Since the length of this string is varying, I can't work with substrings (correct me if I'm wrong).

What is the most efficient (and fastest) way to do this?

EDIT:
@Darin's solution worked fine for most of the messages, but this one here is really tricky:

```
CFG=0<\r><\n>BOU=0<\r><\n>ALA:D1=132,D2=0,D3=0<\r><\n>COD1:S=13<\r><\n>-C1=5,N1=12345678,CLS=0,VAL=0<\r><\n>-C2=5,N2=,CLS=0,VAL=0<\r><\n>COD2:S=0<\r><\n>-C1=0,N1=,CLS=0,VAL=0<\r><\n>ENT:APPEL1=0,APPEL2=0<\r><\n>USI:DEP=0,AES=1,V8K=1,FIL=1,DSP=0,RSC=1,AL3=0,TDA=1,A64=0,CCS=0,RES=0,xxx=0,xxx=0,5AS=1<\r><\n>PERF:<\r><\n>-DMIN=0,0,<\r><\n>OK<\r><\n>
```

I need at least to get the values for S, C1, N1. Even if I remove the line feeds, these parameters are divided either by a comma or by a colon.
How could I handle this string?

Comment: Split pairs by <\r><\n>.

string[] pairs = words.Split(new String[] { @"<\r><\n>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good 'ol split should work:

```
var input = "...some_general_infomations,param1=value1,param2=value2,paramN=valueN";
var tokens = input.Split(',');
if (tokens.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (var token in tokens)
    {
        var parts = token.Split('=');
        if (parts.Length > 1)
        {
            string paramName = parts[0];
            string paramValue = parts[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I will try this and let you now. It's unbelievable how fast I got a response...

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich, this will depend on the project requirement. In my case I am ignoring it as it is malformed. But if there is a requirement to handle the case of malformed string it would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Split` method of the string class.

```
string[] pairs = words.Split(new Char [] {','});
foreach(string pair in pairs)
{
    string[] kv = pair.Split(new Char [] {'='});

    // kv[0] will hold the pair param name
    // kv[1] will hold the pair param value
}
```

There are several assumptions in the code - that you only have pairs of name/value separated by `,` and that each pair has a `=` between the name and the value.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are the standard way to do that; something like so:

```
/,([^=]+)=([^,$]+)/
```

Comment: RegEx seems to be an interesting way to solve this, but have you seen my last edit? How would you get done with that string?

Comment: Is "<\r><\n>" meant to signify a newline, 0x0d 0x0a?

Comment: The following regex would extract the values for S: /\bS=([^,:\r\n]+)/ -- if you're doing this in .NET, you'd loop through the return collection from re.Matches(). If it's not .NET, \b may not be the right way to assert a word boundary. Regexes are a big subject.

Comment: If the value of S is always going to be an integer, you could simplify it: /\bS=(\d+)/, where "\d" matches any decimal digit.